# Getting value of multiple input fields with same class and adding into javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am faced with a issue as follows:

```
<input title="1" type="text" class="email">
<input title="2" type="text" class="email">
<input title="3" type="text" class="email">
```

Above is my html where I am trying to grab the emails of each input box and store it in an object with the title as key.

Here is what my JavaScript currently looks like

```
var emailObj = {};
$("input[class=email]").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("title");
    var email = $(this).val()

    emailObj[id] = email;
});
```

Currently console.log displays only the last value added to the object as shown below.

```
Object { 3="a@a.com"}
```

Where my expected result **should** be as show below

```
Object { 1="a@a.com", 2="b@b.com", 3="c@c.com"}
```

Could someone shed some light on this issue for me please?

Thank you for reading,
Regards.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj24q/.

Comment: Don't know whether its gonna suite your situation or not, but why not use `.serializeArray();` and put the titles as names. you just need to take care on the serverside part coz its gonna be an array of `{name: "", value: ""}`

Comment: @FelixKling He has written correct code, may be he is assuming the code is not working because at the time of code execution textbox values are empty

Answer (score 9):

[There](http://jsfiddle.net/4BWMP/3/) is no problem with your Code. And I would suggest you to write it as utility method

```
function getValues(selector){
  var tempValues = {};
  $(selector).each(function(){
     var th= $(this);
     tempValues[th.attr('title')] = th.val();
   });
  return tempValues;
}

var values = getValues('.email');
```

or If you want values into an array

```
$('.email').map( function(){return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

`.get()` will convert it to a regular array.

The code you have written is absolutely correct. But when I have loaded it was returning me null, because at the time of execution, there were no values in textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `taskArray` is actually an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an array.

Replacing `var taskArray = {}` with this should fix the problem:

```
var taskArray = new Array();
```

**Edit:** on second thoughts, what you have already is perfectly valid!

I'm editing my answer to echo what I've said in the comments: you'll need to debug using the console:

Within the `.each()`, put: `console.log(id);` - the expected result would be "1", "2", "3" - if it's just "3", it probably means that your other inputs aren't being picked up for whatever reason. If that is the result, print out the object after you've assigned the value: `console.log(emailObj[id]);`.

Comment: *What problem?* The code looks absolutely fine to me. Using an object, and calling it `taskArray` is odd, but it's not an error.

Comment: Yeah I've just picked up on that myself! Doh!

Comment: Edited the name, sorry about that =/

Comment: Use the console to print out the value of the id for each element. Within the `.each()`, put: `console.log(id);` - the expected result would be "1", "2", "3" - if it's just "3", it probably means that your other inputs aren't being picked up for whatever reason. If that is the result, print out the object after you've assigned the value: `console.log(emailObj[id]);`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I do see the expected result in the console. However, if I were to print the entire object after the each() the result still remains as my original issue.

Comment: What code are you using to display it after the loop? Have you tried looping through the object? What does `console.log(emailObj[1])` return?