# how to get value of one of the input elements from the same class?

Tags: javascript

Here's my [snippet](http://jsbin.com/vidojesoro/edit?html,js,console,output).

Is there any other way other than appending event listener to every element of the class?
I would like to **avoid loops** if possible.

Comment: There is no other way!

Comment: What is the optimal way then?

Comment: Yes, there is no way which you have provided, why don't you use id's

Comment: http://jsbin.com/motijamigo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Well, I just wanted to value of the input that user entered after "Enter" key

Comment: Maybe this will help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006208/getting-value-of-multiple-input-fields-with-same-class-and-adding-into-javascrip

Comment: @PhoxKiD  Refer the jsbin I have shared..

Comment: @Rayon thanks, it looks great

Comment: @Rayon could you explain a bit ForEach.call

Comment: @PhoxKiD — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't add comment to Jason Cemra.

In addition to His/Her answer the target element as required by PhoxKiD is the input with the class 'inp'. So place a condition

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("keyup", function (event){
    if(event.target.className == 'inp') {
        //your code
    }
    else{  //for other inner elements
        event.preventDefault(); //prevents the default action
        event.stopPropagation(); //stop bubbling up
    }
}
```

Comment: As requested by PhoxKiD, Jason Cemra's approach is without loop/iteration

Comment: Great! btw what does bubbling mean?

Comment: When an event is triggered from an object it bubbles (passes) up towards the object's parent. In the Jason Cemra's answer the event is triggered from the input object and that event bubbles up and handled by its parent. Here in the above code if the event is not triggered from the input with the classname 'inp' the 'event.stopPropagation();' kills the event or pops the bubble out preventing it from further bubbling up.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`[].forEach.call()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053357/what-does-foreach-call-do-in-javascript) to iterate `HTMLCollection`

```js
var user_input = document.getElementsByClassName('inp');
[].forEach.call(user_input, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log(this.value); //this keyword in the handler function refers to element on which event is invoked!
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inp">
<input type="text" class="inp">
<input type="text" class="inp">
```

Comment: Hey! It appears you have copied it from somewhere/...Even the formatting is identical :P

Comment: @Rayon, this line [].forEach.call(user_input,function(el)  is from urs.. rest i was working on my pc, by using this, i was trying for loop

Comment: @MandeepSingh— There is nothing else either.. Never mind! Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks @Rayon, please post your answer with jsbin you provided, learnt one line from you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a single listener to a parent element (in this case `<body>`) and use the event.target attribute to get the DOM node that the event fired off.

This works because the event bubbles up through the DOM hierarchy. It's called "Event Delegation"

See these links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
- https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

**Example Code:**

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">  
    <input type="text" class="inp">
    <input type="text" class="inp">
    <input type="text" class="inp">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: How would you target inside element?